# Making applications for different monitor sizes

Tags: gtk, user-experience

I have been developing an application with the following layout (greatly simplified):

```
+----------------------------------+
|         +----------------+       |
| Main    |                | Info  |
|         |  Interactive   |       |
| Actions |                | And   |
|         |     Graph      |       |
| Go      |                | Forms |
|         |  (Resizable)   |       |
| Here    |                |       |
|         +----------------+       |
+----------------------------------+
```

With a screen resolution of 1440x900. There are some minimum widths set for buttons etc to make them more beautiful (so for example the label inside has some distance from the button borders). Now if I resize the window to about 800x600, it becomes like this:

```
+----------------------+
|         +----+       |
| Main    |    | Info  |
| Actions |    | And   |
|         |    |       |
| Go      |    | Forms |
| Here    |    |       |
|         +----+       |
+----------------------+
```

Which is not so beautiful. *The reason the middle panel gets so small is that the labels on either sides cannot be shrunk.*

**The question is, how can I tell gtk to scale everything (e.g. images, fonts etc) inside a window?**

If such a functionality doesn't exist, what choice do I have for making everything inside the window (or at least the font sizes) smaller or bigger, without having to manually change every widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gtk doesn't allow you to "scale" anything automatically in a window. It would also be a bad idea, as you don't know how little the window will be (not only because of the screen resolution, but because of the user manually resizing the window).

I'd suggest you to redesign your layout. It's complicated to suggest a solution without a real screenshot, but maybe the Main Actions could be replaced in the top part of the window.

Comment: Isn't it for example possible to after checking the screen resolution, call a function that would use a smaller `font-size` attribute than the one already specified by the current theme?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't think it's a good idea. If you set a smaller font in a smaller screen, the result will probably be unreadable.

Anyway, maybe you can win some space making one or both lateral panels hidable, and accesible throught a shortcut key.

Comment: I see. That makes sense, I would think about it.

Comment: Perhaps like gimp, I can turn the application in 3 windows!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of that kind of layout. I'd prefer to completely hide the panel, and allow to show it through an option in the app menu, or/and through a keybind.

Comment: In my particular application, that's not a good option, since both panels are necessary to be able to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use a toolbar with your main actions, and put other actions in a menu bar. This will give more space to the interactive graph. Info and forms, if not required at every moment, may be in a tabbed view, or in a popup. Hard to tell more without a screenshot.